# Searching for data in a file, C

Tags: c, linux

I need to find some data in files, but I'm not sure if my way is correct and above all optimal. The time for the search operation is very limited. The whole operation cannot take more than 100ms. The following code searches the information correctly, but I wonder if there is a better way to search for values in a file. But to the point, I have a file with the following structure. The file structure is always the same, it only differs in the amount of data.

```
#XX-IDDNAME
0155::
#SOMENAME 
3::
/*......there is a lot of uninteresting information here......*/
#SOMEVALUESLIST
2::
1,   .....::
2,   .....::
#NEXTVALUESLIST
5::
1,   .....::
2,   .....::
3,   .....::
4,   .....::
5,   .....::
#SYSTEMTABLELIST
9::
VA1,  120,  33,   XX::
VA2,  120,  13,   XX::
VA3,  120,  13,   XX::
VA4,  90,   7,    XX::
P11,  120,  19,   YY::
P12,  120,  114,  YY::
P13,  120,  19,   YY::
P14,  90,   7,    YY::
PE1,  0,    1,    ZZ::
#CHECKSUMM-BASICPART
12421, 64436::
/*......there is a lot of uninteresting information here......*/
#CHECKSUMM-ALL
39790, 38074::
#END
```

I need to find information following: `#XX-IDNAME`, `#SOMENAME`, `#SYSTEMTABLELIST`, `#CHECKSUMM-BASICPART`, `#CHECKSUMM-ALL`.
I'm currently searching for strings in a file. If I find matching strings then I read the next line as the searched value.
This takes some time as for each value I need to load char by char on the stack.
Below is example for searching ID value. The rest of the values I search in the same way.

```
#define MAXID          7
 
char*   refID = "IDDNAME";
char    valID[MAXID + 1];
char    bufID[MAXID];
int     sppID = 0;

static void pushID(char f)
{
    if(sppID < MAXID ){
        valID[sppID++] = f;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAXID; i++)
        {
                valID[i] = valID[i+1];
        }
        valID[MAXID - 1] = f;
    }
}
void sarchID(void)
{
    FILE* fID = fopen("fileName", "r");
    
    char zei;
    while(strcmp(valID, refID))
    {
        zei= getc(fID);
        pushID(zei);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < MAXID ; i++)
    {
        zei= getc(fID);
        if(zei == ':')
           break;
        bufID[i] = zei;
    }
    trDefConf.IDValue = atoi(bufID);
    fclose(fID);
}
```

Is there any way to improve the search? and is my line of reasoning even correct? If there is a better way to search for values in a file, what should I do?

I also noticed that names always start with a '#' char. I wonder if it would be faster to search for the '#' char, and if I find it, then load all the characters into EOL and then compare if it matches the ref.
If the first char is not '#' then ignore the whole line and move the carriage to a new line.

Comment: Yes, definitely. You should read the file line by line using `fgets` instead of reading it character by character. You also need to check if `fopen` fails. BTW does your code work or not? Using this `pushID` function looks like an extremely convoluted, inefficient and error prone way to me.

Comment: Are you bound to use C? If not, there are several options, starting with AWK and not ending with Python. All of these are simpler to use for the assumed task you have.

Comment: Are the "uninteresting" items all equal in length? If so, you could calculate the lengths of these sections based on the line following each header (which I assume indicates the number of items in the list), and then use `fseek()` to skip directly to the next header.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The code works fine but as you wrote it is convoluted so I am looking for a proper solution to maybe simplify it. Yes right, I need to make a fopen control.

Comment: @thebusybee Unfortunately I am forced to use C or C++. I have more knowledge with C so I used this language

Comment: @r3meiner the lines are not the same length but I have found a pattern where they overlap so I may try to make a new version based on the headers

Comment: Well, then I would go the straight-forward way and use `fgets()` and `strcmp()` and friends. Since the standard library buffers opened streams, this should work out just fine. Benchmark your solution, and only if you are factors too slow, think on another solution. -- How big are the files? Where are they stored, on an SSD or HDD or a network share?

Comment: Currently the largest file I have received is about 270KB but these are just some of the test files, most files do not exceed 100KB. I haven't found any restrictions on file size in the specification, so I think it's only the designer's creativity that limits the size. Files will be stored locally on a >350MB/s drive so this does not seem to be a limitation.